# Complexity of constructive arithmetical truth vs second order arithmetic

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, constructive-mathematics

Let us say that an arithmetic statement is constructively true iff it is realized by a computable function under Kleene's function realizability.  Does the set of constructively true (first order) arithmetic statements have the same Turing degree as the true theory of second order arithmetic?

Kleene's function realizability (which is based on Kleene's second algebra) allows realizers to be arbitrary real numbers, with a realizer for $A⇒B$ being a real number encoding a partial continuous function mapping realizers for $A$ to realizers for $B$.  Thus, every classically true (first order) arithmetical statement has a realizer, but only some have computable realizers. Note that a computable realizer for $A⇒B$ must handle even noncomputable realizers for $A$.

By using function realizability rather than number realizability, we ensure that only classically true arithmetic statements are constructively true.  For example, rather than asserting that if every Turing machine either halts or not then 0=1, it allows reasoning about what can be constructively obtained from an oracle for the halting problem or for other problems.  In my 2006 paper [Constructive Mathematical Truth](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605138), I study the notion in detail, argue that it is the best definition of constructive arithmetical truth, and show that it is $Σ^1_2$-hard and $Π^1_2$-hard.  I left its complexity open, but perhaps there was progress since then or under a different name (rather than constructive arithmetical truth).

*Notes:*
* Modulo choice of encoding, realizers can be elements of $ω^ω$ or $2^ω$ or $ℝ$ (but $ℝ$ is less convenient for coding).
* A partial continuous function extending a partial $f:ω^ω→ω^ω$ can be encoded by any consistent set of pairs $P$ such that $∀x∈\operatorname{dom}(f) \, ∀m \, ∃n \, ((x_0,...,x_n),(f(x)_0,...,f(x)_m))∈P$.
* Other logical symbols are handled as follows.
A realizer for an atomic sentence is trivial (but exists only if the sentence is true).
A realizer for $∃n \, A(n)$ returns $n$ and a realizer for $A(n)$; disjunction is handled similarly.
A realizer for $∀n \, A(n)$ is a function (encoded here by a real number) that for every $n$ gives a realizer for $A(n)$; conjunction is handled similarly.
* Function realizability is commonly used with second order quantifiers $∃X$ and $∀X$ (not needed for the question but interpreted as above), giving a formalization of Brouwer's choice sequences and intuitionistic analysis.  Unlike $¬¬∀n$, the continuity requirement makes $¬¬∀X$ nonclassically strong.

Comment: Can you explain how realizers work with negation?

Comment: I wonder if Dag Normann knows about this problem, it's the sort of thing he knows a great deal about.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: $\alpha$ realizes $\neg A$ iff $A$ has no realizers.

Comment: Is there anything known about the complexity if we use Kleene's first realizability instead?

Comment: It seems to me that the relation "$X$ realizes an arithmetical statement $\phi(x)$" is definable over the SOA, say, $\Sigma^1_n$-definable. Thus we may see a given arithmetical statement $\phi(x)$ is constructively true by looking at true $\Sigma^1_n$ second-order sentences, whose Turing degree seems below that of the full true SOA.

Comment: @HanulJeon For number realizability, the complexity is exactly that of first order arithmetic.  For function realizability, as you write, for every individual $φ$, the constructive truth of $φ(x)$ is definable in second order arithmetic, but the complexity depends on $φ$, which each nesting of implications appearing to require an additional second order quantifier.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I forgot about implications.